# How can I get the mean of only one column of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to get the mean of the mathematics column of the following matrix. How can I do this?
I have this data

```
 > female
        Statistics Mathematics Chemistry
  Ann           62          70        61
  Nicky         62          57        29
```

I tried it as below. I only want the mean of Mathematics.

```
  > colMeans(female)
  Statistics Mathematics   Chemistry 
       62.0        63.5        45.0
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You can susbet the matrix using `[]`, like this: `mean(mat[,2])`

Comment: @DanielR Hello! I tried this but i get an error. Do i have to convert the matrix to a data frame?

Comment: No. Maybe because the columns are named, but it was supposed to work. Try the answers linked by the moderator.

Comment: @DanielR  Alright. Thank you.